Почему div не растягивается в зависимости от контента?
Ситуация приведшая к вопросу.
Имеем большую картинку(или какой-то широкий блок), допустим в 2 раза шире экрана, на котором смотрим. Картинка находится на странице, на которой html, body не имеют явно указанного размера. Мы хотим разместить над картинкой какие-то интерактивные элементы. Для этого оборачиваем картинку div'ом и ожидаем, что так как div не имеет явно указанной ширины, то он примет размер контента. Но не тут-то было. Div примет ширину вьюпорта. Почему? Почему контент не влияет на ширину div?
https://jsfiddle.net/f4nztab3/1/
Как видим в примере - #strangeSize - не принимает размер широкого вложенного блока шириной 5000 пикселей, а принимает размер вьюпорта. Почему?
Нашлось решение в виде значения width: fit-content; но поддержка этого значения относительно свежая. Я всегда думал что div, если не задан конкретный размер или его ограничения, занимают или всю доступную ширину если контент меньше, или принимают размер вложенных элементов.
Так почему div не растягивается в зависимости от контента?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

«… и ожидаем, что […] он примет размер контента» — это неверное ожидание. https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#Computing_widths_and_margins

@AlexeyTen Да это известная формула, ширина блока = ширина и сумма всего остального, марджинов, пэддингов, бордеров. width - в авто и должна определяться содержимым, т.е. в итоге должна быть равна 5000px, а не ширине вьюпорта. Почему вы утверждаете что мои ожидания не верны?

Где там написано «должна определяться содержимым»?

@AlexeyTen Идём в пункт 10.3.3 жмём на width в формуле. и в описании видим
The content width of a non-replaced inline element’s boxes is that of the rendered content within them (before any relative offset of children).

Ваш div это НЕ «non-replaced inline element». Ну и вообще вы вырвали это из контекста, в котором сказано что свойство width к таким элементам неприменимо в принципе. А у вас Block-level, non-replaced elements in normal flow и там написано что ширина элемента при width:auto это ширина родителя минус border/margin/padding у блока. Всё. Содержимое этого блока никак не учитывается.

@AlexeyTen Спасибо.
Тогда ещё одним решением будет { display: inline-block; }

На данный момент fit-content уже поддерживает все устройства кроме IE-9

В итоге получается, что div, не смотря на то, что ему ничто не мешает расширяться, принимает размер равный ширине родительского элемента, а она равна ширине viewPort'а, а ширина содержимого div не влияет на ширину div, т.к. он обычный блочный элемент в стандартном потоке вывода.
Решения два:

display: inline-block;
Тогда контент будет влиять на ширину блока.
width: fit-content;
Это уже более свежий вариант введёный для grid элементов.

Вообще, на мой взгляд, это не логичное поведение, т.к. ни один из блоков не имеет ограничений или фиксированных размеров, то контент должен влиять на их ширину, хотя бы на ширину документа, они же оборачивают содержимое, значит и размер должны иметь как у него.
Но, видимо, у разработчиков стандарта были свои резоны так сделать. Жаль, что никто не объяснит какие.
Спасибо @Alexey Ten за участие.
